# jQuery fullcalendar send custom parameter and refresh calendar with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the jQuery fullcalendar. The event data comes from the server using JSON.
My page has a dropdown element and the fullcalendar div.

What I need is to refresh the calendar each time the user changes the dropdown. The selected value of the dropdown should be posted to the server in order to fetch the new event data.

Here is my code:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: {
                url : '/myfeed',
                data : {personId : $('#personDropDown').val() }
            }
        });

        $('#personDropDown').change(function(){
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        });

    });
```

However, the code above doesn't work.
Any help?

Comment: what does /myfeed see / do ? I presume that it receives the querystring value "personId" and performs a lookup to return the json source? refetchEvents should do it (according to the doco) but perhaps you also need to also call 'rerenderEvents'. Have you done a trace (e.g. Fiddler, if you are on Windows) to capture the data being posted / returned?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: {
            url: '/myfeed',
            data: function () { // a function that returns an object
                return {
                    personId: $('#personDropDown').val(),
                };

            }
        });


    $('#personDropDown').change(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    });

});
```

Comment: This is THE solution. According to the documentation of fullcalendar http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ in the section `Dynamic data parameter`

Answer (score 31):

Finally it worked with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        loadCalendar();
        $('#siteSelect').change(function(){
            var selectedSite = $('#siteSelect').val();
            var events = {
                  url: '/myfeed2',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {
                    siteid: selectedSite
                  }
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', events);
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
        });

    });
```

Comment: Maybe this work but the fullcalendar documentation say @jairo answer is the correct. http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ in `Dynamic data parameter`

Comment: This solution is outdated. The better one is now what @inye and jairo are suggesting.

Answer (score 4):

This works on at least 2.0.2. `data` becomes a function that returns an object populated with dynamic dropdown values. `change` is added to refresh the calendar when a new dropdown value is selected.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    events: {
        url: "/myfeed",
        data: function() {
            return {
                dynamicValue: $("#dropdownList").val()
            };
        },
        type: "POST"
    }
});

$("#dropdownList").change(function () {
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  At least put me on the right track to get my calendar figured out.  Thank you!

Comment: Not works for me.  $("#overviewDatePicker").datepicker(
 {
  onSelect: function(event){
 var start=$("#overviewDatePicker").val();
 var end="2016-10-21";
 $.ajax({
  url:"fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php?mode=customdate&start="+start+"&end="+end,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(result){
   console.log(result);
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', result); 
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );   
  }
      });
           },
  });

Answer (score 3):

I refresh this way after an ajax event adds an event using a modal for instance:

```
$('#cal').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
$('#cal').fullCalendar('addEventSource', "../calendar/json-events2.php")
$('#cal').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

Comment: Not works for me.  $("#overviewDatePicker").datepicker(
 {
  onSelect: function(event){
 var start=$("#overviewDatePicker").val();
 var end="2016-10-21";
 $.ajax({
  url:"fullcalendar/demos/php/get-events.php?mode=customdate&start="+start+"&end="+end,
  type:"GET",
  success:function(result){
   console.log(result);
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', result); 
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents' );   
  }
      });
           },
  });

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are changing the value of the dropdown after you have created the event object, which has a **copy** of the original value of the dropdown. The following is what you need:

```
$('#dropdownId').change(function () {
    events.data.customParam = $(this).val();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});
```

This relies on the event object being created in an area where it can be accessed from the dropdown onchange and the fullcalendar initialisation (e.g. document onload)

Answer (score 1):

I solved like this

```
         data: function() { // a function that returns an object
         return {
                 custom_param1: date_start,
             custom_param2: date_end
            };
         },
```

after modifying the values date_start and date_end, this function gets the new values.
In my case i take the dates when the view changes

```
viewRender: function(view,element){
       date_start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(view.start,'dd/MM/yyyy');
       date_end   = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(view.end,'dd/MM/yyyy');
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get that to work either. 
So I ended up with solution similar to this:

```
$('#personDropDown').change(function () {
            var source = {
                data: {
                    filter: $('#personDropDown').val()
                },
                 url : '/myfeed'
            };
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using function as event source. On refetchEvents event fullCalendar calls function that returns custom value and will post it to service.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#valueSelect').change(function(){
            if ($('#calendar').hasClass('fc'))
            {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: function(start, end, callback) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'web-service-link',
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: {
                                start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
                                end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000),
                                customValue: GetCustomValue()
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
});

function GetCustomValue()
{
    return $('#valueSelect').val();
{
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself and there is a more dynamic way of doing this since the value is stored when the calendar is initialized and the data object needs modified.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: {
                url : '/myfeed',
                data : {personId : $('#personDropDown').val() }
            }
        });

        $('#personDropDown').change(function(){
            $('#calendar').data('fullCalendar').options.events.data.personId = $(this).val();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is right way.

$.ajax({
    url: 'ABC.com/Calendar/GetAllCalendar/',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    data: { Id: 1 },
    success: function (data) {
        obj = JSON.stringify(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, err) {
        alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
        alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
});

/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //isRTL: true,
    buttonHtml: {
        prev: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
        next: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    //obj that we get json result from ajax
    events: JSON.parse(obj)
    ,
    editable: true,
    selectable: true    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using this :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'destroy' );
```

when I select other option in the dropdown, I don't know if is elegant but works!