# Fullcalendar - extraParams in events and eventsources not being read from element.value

Tags: javascript, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

**The Setup**

I'm using Fullcalendar v4, and I'm having some trouble with `extraParams` and sending them to server via AJAX.

What I'm trying to do (and failing) is to use this:

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction','dayGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror:true,
         .......
        eventSources: [{
            url: 'ajax/fc.php?dropdown='+$("#dropdown").val(),
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            extraParams: {
                month: $("#monthPicker").val(),
                dropdown: $("#dropdown").val(),
                person: $("#person").val(),
                phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
                testtext: 'hardcoded text'
            },
        }],
         ......
    });
```

Values for month, dropdown, person, phone are picked up from a form.

**The Problem**

Dumping both the `GET` and the `POST` variables (sever-side), just to check what I've received gives back 0 / empty strings for everything other than the `month` parameter - it's shown correctly.

The `GET` parameter is there just for testing purposes, and so is `document.getElementById` bit - I wanted to see if anything would show up if I used them (nothing did).

The issue persists even if I change the code to use `events` instead of `eventSources`.

Upon further experimenting, it seems that the calendar is affected by the element values present upon **its initialization** - if I hardcode the values for dropdown, person, and other inputs / select elements, they, and only they get sent (any change in values is ignored). The same thing happens if I just set the initial value (ie `<input id="person" name="person" value="Joe">`).

**The question**

How can I force the `calendar` (short of destroying and recreating it) to actually notice changes in the input values I want to use as `extraParams`?

If I'm misunderstanding the use of `extraParams`, what are my alternatives? I need to be able to send various data to the server, in order to get a specific set of events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in the meantime, thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19602629). Since the parameters are dynamic, they need to be sent as stated [in the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/events-json-feed) (part Dynamic `extraParams` parameter):

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

  events: {
    url: '/myfeed.php',
    extraParams: function() { // a function that returns an object
      return {
        dynamic_value: Math.random()
      };
    }
  }

});
```

Which, in my case, would become:

```
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction','dayGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror:true,
         .......
        event: {
            url: 'ajax/fc.php',
            method: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            extraParams: function() {
                return {
                    month: $("#monthPicker").val(),
                    dropdown: $("#dropdown").val(),
                    person: $("#person").val(),
                    phone: document.getElementById("phone").value,
                    testtext: 'hardcoded text'
                }
            },
        },
         ......
    });
```